# Realm Hierarchical Structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am checking the possibility to use Realm in my next Objective-C Project.
Is it possible to create a structure for hierarchical objects ? For example folders and file like a filesystem?

For example if I want to define a structure like the following:

```
- Web Site
 - Folder 1
   - F1_File1
   - F1_File2
   - F1_File3
   - F1_Folder1
     - F1_Sub_File1
     - F1_Sub_File2
 - Folder 2
   - F2_File1
   - F2_File2
   - F2_File3
   - F2_Folder1
     - F2_Sub_File1
     - F2_Sub_File2
```

How can I manage this situation?
Is it possible to perform query to retrieve the entire structure of a specific node?
For example given the F2_Folder identifier i'd like to retrieve the parent structure or its childs. Is it possible?

Could you point me to a tutorial on in the right direction? 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

In Realm, once you retrieve a particular object you can retrieve the parent and child objects when you actually query them. Realm behave in a lazy-loading way. For example you have this Realm Object:

```
@interface File : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property File *parent;
@property RLMArray<File*><File> *children;
@end

// Retrieve a particular Object
File *obj = [File objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"F2_Folder1"] firstObject];

// Retrieve the children
RLMResults children = obj.children;

// Retrieve the parent
File *parent = obj.parent;
```